# How to replace SQL field value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I really don't know exactly what to do, I'm a bit new to SQL. Should I use `substring` or `replace` in my case?

I have a field in my DB called "email", now I wanted to edited all email ending with "email.com" to "email.org". What shall I do?

Comment: Title doesn't really match question. For single change do: UPDATE yourtable SET email='contact@gmail.org' WHERE uid='10';

Answer (score 60):

It depends on what you need to do. You can use [`replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) since you want to replace the value:

```
select replace(email, '.com', '.org')
from yourtable
```

Then to `UPDATE` your table with the new ending, then you would use:

```
update yourtable
set email = replace(email, '.com', '.org')
```

You can also expand on this by checking the last 4 characters of the email value:

```
update yourtable
set email = replace(email, '.com', '.org')
where right(email, 4) = '.com'
```

However, the issue with `replace()` is that `.com` can be will in other locations in the email not just the last one. So you might want to use [`substring()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) the following way:

```
update yourtable
set email = substring(email, 1, len(email) -4)+'.org'
where right(email, 4) = '.com';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/720c2/5)

Using `substring()` will return the start of the email value, without the final `.com` and then you concatenate the `.org` to the end.  This prevents the replacement of `.com` elsewhere in the string.

Alternatively you could use [`stuff()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx), which allows you to do both deleting and inserting at the same time:

```
update yourtable
set email = stuff(email, len(email) - 3, 4, '.org')
where right(email, 4) = '.com';
```

This will delete 4 characters at the position of the third character before the last one (which is the starting position of the final `.com`) and insert `.org` instead.

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/720c2/7) for this method as well.

Comment: [`REPLACE(string_expression, string_pattern, string_replacement)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql)

Comment: For non-English characters do not forget N prefix. `replace(email, N'.com', N'.org')`

Answer (score 11):

You could just use [`REPLACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx):

```
UPDATE myTable SET emailCol = REPLACE(emailCol, '.com', '.org')`.
```

But take into account an email address such as `john.comrad@some.company.com` will be updated to `john.orgrad@some.organy.org`.

If you want to be on a safer side, you should check for the last 4 characters using [`RIGHT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), and append `.org` to the [`SUBSTRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) manually instead. Notice the usage of [`UPPER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180055%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to make the search for the `.com` ending case insensitive.

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET emailCol = SUBSTRING(emailCol, 1, LEN(emailCol)-4) + '.org'
WHERE UPPER(RIGHT(emailCol,4)) = '.COM';
```

See it working in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cad7a/6).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid update names that contain `.com` like `john.comrad@email.com` to `john.orgrad@email.org`, you can do this:

```
UPDATE Yourtable
SET Email = LEFT(@Email, LEN(@Email) - 4) + REPLACE(RIGHT(@Email, 4), '.com', '.org')
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this query it ll change the records ends with .com

```
 UPDATE tablename SET email = replace(email, '.com', '.org') WHERE  email LIKE '%.com';
```

Comment: -1: This will replace everywhere in the email address. It would double fail with `john.comrad@some.company.com`